# Struts2 propertytag

Tags: jsp, properties, struts2

I am trying to use Struts2 property tag to display the value from a bean. My code in the jsp page is as follow:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<s:bean name="com.section.entity.SectionOrder" var="sectionOrder" />
<th colspan="4" class="head">
<s:property value="#sectionOrder.name" /></th>  
</tr>
</thead>
```

However there is no output. Hope someone can advise. Thank you.

Comment: You've created an instance of your object but its properties are not set. Why should it print anything?

Comment: Hi Aleksandr, before this jsp page is fired a DAO class is invoked which does it's dB operations and set's the values in the SectionOrder object. I did not post that code earlier, here it is

    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

Comment: I am not able to get the formatting right when I 'Add Comment' here... I am sorry for the inconvenience guys...:(

Comment: Add code in your question not in comments. If an instance of your object is created outside of jsp, why do you using `<s:bean>` to create a new instance? Don't use `<s:bean>` and get it from action class.

Comment: mmmmm.... I saw an example in a site that uses <s:bean> to get the property from a bean other than the action class....Why do you say it shouldn't be done this way?

http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-property-tag-example/

Comment: Read again this example. They use `<s:bean>` to show how instance could be created and how retrieve pre-defined value from it. Keep it simple and if you are not sure what specific tag do, read official documentation and not some tutorial.

Comment: @Sor In the linked example you should use a first method, the link is good.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare the var, if your action has a getter and a setter for that variable, with the same name, you just use

```
<s:property value="sectionOrder.name" /></th>
```

The java class must have a setter and a getter with the same name

```
public YourTypeOfObject getSectionOrder() {
    return this.sectionOrder;
}
public void setSectionOrder(YourTypeOfObject sectionOrder) {
    this.sectionOrder = sectionOrder;
}
```

Also, the sectionOrder object also has to have a getter for the name variable.

```
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
```

Hope it helps.